# Vuex create search filter

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm new to `VueJs` and `Vuex` and I want to create a simple search filter. My app looks like this.

- Items -> parent
- ItemToolbar -> child
- ItemList -> child

**Items.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ItemToolbar></ItemToolbar>
    <ItemList :allItems="allItems"></ItemList>
  </div>
</template>

computed: {
  ...mapGetters(["allItems"])
}
```

So I try to create a filter in **getters** called `searchByTitle`.

```
const getters = {
 allItems: state => state.items,
 searchByTitle: state => searchValue => {
    const search = searchValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    return state.items.filter(
      item => item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1
    );
   }
};
```

My problem the value of `searchValue` will come from `ItemToolbar` component and I don't know where to use `searchByTitle` should I call it to `ItemToolbar` component or in the `Items` component.

Answer (score 0):

I would emit event from `ItemToolbar.vue` to `Items.vue`, that then will decide which items it have to show: if title is present – filtered, if not – all items.

```
<template>
<div>
   <ItemToolbar @filter="title = $event"></ItemToolbar>
   <ItemList :all-items="filteredItems"></ItemList>
</div>
</template>

...
data() {
  return {
    title: '',
  }
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['allItems', 'searchByTitle']),
  filteredItems() {
    return this.title ? this.searchByTitle(title) : allItems
  },
},
...
```

And emit that `title` from `ItemToolbar.vue`:

```js
this.$emit('filter', VALUE_OF_THE_TITLE')
```